Adding the highlightjs API interface to self in a web worker?
I'm coding a web worker in Typescript and this works:
onmessage = (e) => {
    importScripts(
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.10.0/highlight.min.js'
    );
    const language = e.data.language;
    const result = language
      ? (self as any).hljs.highlightAuto(e.data.code, { language })
      : (self as any).hljs.highlightAuto(e.data.code);
    postMessage(result.value);
  };

I'm curious if there is a way to type self more strictly with the types from @types/highlightjs?

Why do you even need self here?

Why do you want to add globals? That's usually a bad idea. This smells like an XY Problem. What is the the problem that caused you to seek this solution?

The self is the global context in Web Workers.  Web Workers have their own global context, like Window for the global browser tab thread.  The functionimportScripts allows web workers to add additional API the global web workers self context.

This is the web worker reference Javascript for how to implement a highlightjs web woker in pure Javascript.

Yes, but just like window in a Window context you don't need to use it for every global variables. Why not  just do hljs.highlightAuto(... directly?

@Kaiido because importScripts imports and attaches the hljs object containing the highlightjs API to self.

But as you said, self is actually globalThis, which is the same as window in a Window context. Just like you don't need to do window.document, (or even globalThis.window.document etc.) there is no need to get it from self here, hljs === self.hljs && hljs === globalThis.hljs.

@Kaiido ok I see what you are saying.  I think I can just import * as hljs from "highlightjs";  and use hljs directly like you are saying.  At first I thought specifying self is something we had to do within web workers ... Thanks for all the hints ... I'm testing it out now ...

You don't even need to use the esm version if the rest of your project doesn't use esm, self === globalThis: that's the global object on which global variables are accessed. Just like you do directly importScripts() and postMessage() instead of self.importScripts() or self.postMessage(), you can access self.hljs directly as hljs.

@Kaiido OK I finally got the setup figured out to properly test this.  If we try to use hljs by itself, typescript creates this linting error Cannot find name 'hljs'.ts(2304).

So it seems that in workers we do need to have the self context ...
